# Javascript age validation

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing javascript validation and everything's working perfectly except my age validation. If the person enters a value of type string it must give an alert for the user to enter his/her age as a numeric value...

I'm not quite sure how to go about this so your help will be very much appreciated!

You will see what I'm trying to do in the validAge function in the if-statement: line 55

Here is my code I have so far!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Question 1 / Vraag 1 - Basic JavaScript Validaton / Basiese JavaScript validasie
    </title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script language="javascript">

                function validate()
                {
                    var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname");
                    var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
                    var age = document.getElementById("age");
                    var email = document.getElementById("email");

                    if(notEmpty(firstname, "ENTER USERNAME"))
                    {
                        if(notEmpty(surname, "ENTER SURNAME"))
                        {
                            if(notEmpty(age, "ENTER AGE"))
                            {
                                if(validAge(age, "AGE MUST BE A NUMERIC VALUE"))
                                {
                                    if(notEmpty(email, "ENTER EMAIL"))
                                    {
                                        if(emailValid(email, "ENTER A PROPER EMAIL ADDRESS"))
                                        {
                                            return emailValid();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg)
                {
                    if(elem.value.length == 0)
                    {
                        alert(helperMsg);
                        elem.focus();
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }


                function validAge(elem, helperMsg)
                {
                    var age = elem.value;

                    if(age <= 0 || age > 100 || age.type == string???))
                    {
                        alert(helperMsg);
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }


                function emailValid(elem, helperMsg)
                {
                    var atpos = elem.value.indexOf("@");
                    var dotpos = elem.value.lastIndexOf(".");

                    if(atpos < 0 || dotpos < 0)
                    {
                        alert(helperMsg);
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                }

        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> Firstname:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" /><span id="fnError">
        </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Surname:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname"/><span id="snError">
        </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td> Age:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="age" id="age"/><span id="aError">
        </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>  Email:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/><span id="eError">
        </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="button" value="Validate" onClick="validate()" /></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a RegExp to check whether it's a valid age. Methods such as `isNaN` will still allow floating-point numbers, though I have never heard anyone saying *`My age is twelve dot three`*.:

```
    function validAge(elem, helperMsg)
    {
        var age = elem.value;
       //Two digits, so anything between and including 0 and 99
        if(/^\d{1,2}$/,test(age)) 
        {
            alert(helperMsg);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Another tip: Instead of nesting hundreds of `if`-conditions, you can also use the logical `&&` (AND) operator.

```
if(a){
  if(b){
    if(c){
       ...
```

can be shortened to:

```
if(a && B && c){
```

Comment: But if the user decides to input it as e.g. "twelve" it must alert him that it must be numeric like "12".

Comment: @Joemeister That's possible, but not reliable. The user could spell the number wrongly, or completely different. You'd b better only accept numbers. Also, if I had a choice to put in a number, I would enter `12`, not ``twelve`.

Comment: You could do `+age === parseInt(age)` if you only wanted to allow integer ages.

Comment: What if the user is older than 99?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [isNan](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) function!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
if(isNaN(age) || age <= 0 || age > 100))
```

The `isNaN(age)` uses the [`isNaN`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) function to check whether or not `age` is actually a number.

Note that this will allow floating point ages, which may or may not be what you want. If you prefer, you can only allow integer ages with this condition:

```
age % 1 === 0
```

Also, I would avoid nesting all the `if` statements. You could do a return after each one, like this:

```
if(notEmpty(firstname, "ENTER USERNAME")) return false;
if(notEmpty(surname, "ENTER SURNAME")) return false;
if(notEmpty(age, "ENTER AGE")) return false;
/// skip a few ...
return emailValid();
```

BTW, there are some people who are over 100 years old. This app would be bad for their user experience.

Comment: Haha, yeah it's just for testing! I'll put the max at around 150 years?? :P Thanks fo your help!

Comment: For testing whether a number is not a floating point, you'd better use `age%1==0` instead of `parseInt`. If you want to stick to parseInt, use `+age === parseInt(age, 10)`. Why? Because `parseInt('08')` equals zero.

Comment: @RobW Actually, `parseInt("08")` returns `8`. But I know what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Try this using [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN):

```
  function validAge(elem, helperMsg)
  {
       var age = elem.value;
       // If age is Not a Number,  not at least 1, greater than 100,  or has a decimal place.

       if(isNaN(age) || age <= 0 || age > 100 || age.indexOf(".") >= 0)
       {
              alert(helperMsg);
              return false;
       }

       return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct.. If you think of re-usability please have a look at this [plugin](http://www.onegeek.com.au/projects/javascript-form-validation). It validates a form with small effort..

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Name</title>
<script>
function validatetext()
{
    if(document.sign.fname.value=="")
    {
        alert("Missing First name!");
    }
    if(isNaN(document.sign.age())
    {
        alert("Enter numaric");
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body><form method=post name="sign">
<b>name:</b>
<input name="fname" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" />
<br>
<b>age:</b>
<input name="age" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" />
<input type="submit" name="signup"  value="sign up" onclick="validatetext();" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```